# How to return value in python unittest patch decorator only

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I need to return a value in python unittest patch decorator not in function.

I am writing unit test case for a fucntion in which I want to return the the value directly in the decorator not in unittest function.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: I am writing some unitests in which the mocked function should return a tuple with two values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to permanently mock return value of a function in python unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139563/how-to-permanently-mock-return-value-of-a-function-in-python-unittest)

Comment: Though the answer seems to the one shared by you, but my question is entirely different from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@patch('module_name.function_name',mock.MagicMock(return_value={}))
```

You can return whatever value you want instead of empty JsonResponse.